# Wordpress stylesheets doesnt load

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently building a plugin for Wordpress, but my style and scripts doesn't load in the view page.

Function:

```
function getFrontEnd() 
{
   // we always need jquery
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   // load the core plugin scripts/styles
   wp_enqueue_script('flex-script', __DIR__ . '/view/assets/js/wp-flex.js');
   wp_enqueue_style('flex-style', __DIR__ . '/view/assets/css/wp-flex.css');
}
```

View:

```
function getFlexImportView()
{
   $pluginIndex = new controllers\FlexImport;

   echo $pluginIndex->getOverview();
}
```

And in the class FlexImport you will find an include to the file that execute the html.

Both of the style files aren't in the html file after inspect them.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there someone that can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start by checking the file path. Use this :

wp_enqueue_style('flex-script', plugin_dir_url( **FILE** ) . 'view/assets/js/wp-flex.js' );

Comment: the path is correct but the hole style doesnt load on the plugin page, that is the issue.